# Approaches for a Database Middleware

Tags: database, microservices, middleware, access-control

We are building a platform in form of a microservice architecture which shall be open to add services from several companies.

The services shall use a common data warehouse (including a NoSQL database and an Object Store) provided by the platform to exchange data between services.

The services should **not** have access to all data. E.g.: Service 1 may write something to the NoSQL database and Service 2 is only allowed to read the data written by Service 1.

In our opinion it makes sense to give services not direct access to the data bases for security reasons. We are searching for a kind of database middleware which allows to realize such access functionalities. If possible this middleware should be scalable in terms of the number of services and their volume of pushed/pulled data.

Do you may have some ideas for suitable approaches/technologies?

Thanks!

Comment: Informatica, Axiomatics... are all solutions that tackle this